# Are any standard library modules missing from `print( help('modules'))`

Tags: python, python-3.x, standard-library

In a very brief python script, we can write:

```
print( help('modules'))
```

This lists a great number of things, including the following:

```
PIL                 _weakrefset         html                secrets
__future__          _winapi             http                select
_abc                _xxsubinterpreters  idlelib             selectors
_ast                abc                 imaplib             setuptools
```

Note that some non-standard libraries are included. For example, I have `PIL` installed for image processing. My question is, are any of the standard libraries **missing** from `print( help('modules'))`? Basically, I want to print a list of the names of all python standard libraries to file. My attempt is shown below:

```
import os
import pathlib as pl
import string
from contextlib import redirect_stdout


class FileFilter:

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        filepath = pl.Path(str(filepath))
        if os.path.exists(filepath):
            os.remove(filepath)
        # open in `append` mode
        self._file = open(filepath, "a")
        self.prev_was_comma = False

    def write(self, stuff):
        lamby = lambda ch:\
            "," if ch in string.whitespace else ch
        mahp = map(lamby, str(stuff))
        for ch in mahp:
            if ch != "," or not self.prev_was_comma:
                self._file.write(ch)
            if ch == ",":
                self.prev_was_comma = True
            else:
                self.prev_was_comma = False

    def __del__(self):
        self._file.close()


with redirect_stdout(FileFilter("stdlibs.txt")):
    help('modules')

# TODO:
# remove opening line
#     ,Please,wait,a,moment,while,I,gather,a,list,of,all,available,modules...,
# remove closing line
#     ,Enter,any,module,name,to,get,more,help.,Or,type,"modules,spam"
#     to,search,for,modules,whose,name,or,summary,contain,the,string,"spam".,
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Comment: Just use `pip list` in the terminal or cmd

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.10 you can use [sys.stdlib_module_names](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/sys.html#sys.stdlib_module_names).

You can also take a look at [sys.builtin_module_names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names) if that is what you need.